# How to change radio button background image on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a subscription plan and I want to use images as radio button background. On-click of the image button the background image should change to another checked image.

[image]

I have done like this

```
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="hiddenradio">
        <label class="layersMenu">
        <input type="radio" id="radioZoom14" name="zoomsMBtiles" value="14" checked />
        <img src="/assets/img/plan-box-hover.png">
        
    </label>

    <label class="layersMenu">
        <input type="radio" id="radioZoom18" name="zoomsMBtiles" value="18" />
        <img src="/assets/img/plan-box-selected.png">
      
    </label>
    </div>
```

And Its CSS

```
    label { display: inline-block }
    label > input {  
      visibility: hidden; 
      position: absolute; 
    }
    label > input + img {  
      cursor:pointer;
      border:2px solid transparent;
    }
    label > input:checked + img {  
     background: url("/assets/img/plan-box-selected.png");
    }
```

I can't able to change the background image. Please help. I have two PNG images.

Radio Button : plan-box.png
On Hover : plan-box-selected.png

Comment: Did you take a look into the hover selector? 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: I want it on radio button checked

Answer (score 1):

you can't use "background-image" property for "img" tag.

you can use jQuery or javascript to change "src" attribute of your "img" tag:

```
$("label.layersMenu").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src" , "img-address-2");
  }, function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src" , "img-address-1");
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank You! It's working on hover but after click img-address-2 not working.

Comment: you should use this functions on Click Event too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take the control of radio button styling using the following property on the radio input.

```
input {
-webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;}
```

Then you have to use height, width, border, background-color, etc to get the desired properties. Here is my Codepen example:

https://codepen.io/jagadeesh-kumar/pen/oNBwdPM

MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio